# Using Swiftmailer without a framework

Tags: php, swiftmailer

I am wanting to use Swiftmailer as a standalone library without Symfony, Laravel, Yii, composer, etc.

According to the [Swiftmailer website](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/introduction.html) the way to include the library is by calling composer's autoload.php, however I am not using composer in this case and would like to know which base files in /vender/swiftmailer need to be included in order to use the library instead of `require_once '/path/to/vendor/autoload.php';`

I looked at the Swiftmailer [Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/swiftmailer/V9pZhfiZjaI), but it's been discontinued and says to come here.

Thanks

Comment: Looking at their [`composer.json` file](https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/blob/master/composer.json), it looks like you just need to include `lib/swift_required.php` and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks @rickdenhaan I will give that a try.

Comment: You can, also, download their zipped code from the repository on GitHub: https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer put it in a folder of you project and import the lib/swift_required.php file

Comment: Yes I did that, but it's still constructed for use with composer.

Comment: Well now I am wondering if composer is installing another 3rd party library.

I installed the Swiftmailer library manually without composer using git clone and when I go to instantiate the Swift_Message class, I get the following:

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ReflectionException: Class Egulias\EmailValidator\EmailValidator does not exist in /local/mail-handler/vendor/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/DependencyContainer.php:309

Answer (score 3):

As you have discovered, if you are putting the Swiftmailer into a website without anything to help with the loading, you will need to add your own autoloader for the external dependencies.

There are two for Swiftmailer v6.1.0:
https://github.com/egulias/EmailValidator
and another
https://github.com/doctrine/lexer

Including swiftlib/swift_required.php autoloads all the swift classes. You could add the autoload for the others into the same file. Here's an example where the two dependencies have been copied into subdirectories of the swiftlib folder:

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {

    $load_deps = [ 
        'Egulias\\EmailValidator\\' => __DIR__ . '/EmailValidator/',
        'Doctrine\\Common\\Lexer\\' => __DIR__ . '/Doctrine/Common/Lexer/',
    ];

    foreach ($load_deps as $prefix => $base_dir) {
        // does the class use the namespace prefix?
        $len = strlen($prefix);
        if (strncmp($prefix, $class, $len) == 0) {

            // get the relative class name
            $relative_class = substr($class, $len);

            // replace the namespace prefix with the base directory, replace namespace
            // separators with directory separators in the relative class name, append
            // with .php
            $file = $base_dir . str_replace('\\', '/', $relative_class) . '.php';

            // if the file exists, require it
            if (file_exists($file)) {
                require $file;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was able to simply use composer and it generated the autoload file and so to use it in my code all that I needed was a require statement for the autoloader. Works great!

 require_once. 'path/to/vendor/autoload.php';

Comment: Yes, when you have a development environment with composer you can use it to generate an autoloader. Your question said you can't use composer so my answer tells you a way of doing it without. However, I'm glad you overcame your obstacles.