# Issues while trying to install SwiftMailer without composer. Trying to send smtp email with pdf via php

Tags: php, email, swiftmailer

I am facing some pain trying to install another one php library without composer and other stuff.
What did I do:

1. In the same folder where executable script (`index.php`) is situated I created folder `fpdf`;
2. In `fpdf` created folder `lib` and unziped there all from https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/tree/master/lib ;
3. In `lib` created folders `Doctrine` and `EmailValidator` and unziped there stuff from https://github.com/doctrine/lexer and https://github.com/egulias/EmailValidator respectively;
4. In the end of `swift_required.php` file I added code from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50105900/15749307.

Getting error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?' in /home/virtwww/w_imaimachi_0f858928/http/fpdf/lib/EmailValidator/Validation/MessageIDValidation.php on line 47

line 47:     public function getError() : ?InvalidEmail;
```

I have PHP 7 i guess.

If this nightmare can be end, please tell me how. If there is other library for sending email (I need to send a pdf as a string but not a file) that may easy to install without composer or another framework, or if there another non-third-party solution, please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

It is not answer on the exact question but this is the code fro sending pdf through smtp that worked for me

1. Download "mailer" (only few php file) and extract to some folder on server https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer.
2. In your executable php file (index.php or whatever) add code:

Code (if I paste right after list above the syntax highlighting breaks for some reason):

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'path/to/src/Exception.php';
require 'path/tp/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'path/to/src/SMTP.php';
```

And the code that will send pdf as binary string (**not base64!**):

```
function mail_attachment($pdf) 
{
$mail = new PHPMailer();

// Settings
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';

$mail->Host       = "smtp.server.ua"; // SMTP server example
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 0;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Port       = 25;                    // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
$mail->Username   = "login"; // SMTP account username example
$mail->Password   = "passwrod";        // SMTP account password example

$mail->setFrom('aga@ugu.com', 'Mailer');
//$mail->addAddress('joe@example.net', 'Joe User');     //Add a recipient
$mail->addAddress('okumaima@outlook.com');        

// Content
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';
$mail->AddStringAttachment($pdf, 'file.pdf'); // not base64 !

echo $mail->send();
}
```

Should work, hope it will help someone.